# What's the best way to hide the hero (or other modules) when the on the details view of a 2sxc app?

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a simple 2sxc app that is a listing and details for special resources. So I have two C# Razor templates - one for listing, and one for details.

When I click into the details view, the details template shows content. But I want to hide the hero banner module (another DNN 2sxc module) I have on the page. Because the app exists on one DNN page, the hero module will appear for both, naturally. I want this hero to appear on the listing, but not the details.

Is there some kind of special DNN and/or 2sxc C# razor code I can put inside the details.csthml to make it so this app module is the only module that appears on that page? I know I can simply use CSS to hide the hero, but I was curious if there's a better method.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the Details are being displayed instead of the List because something is triggering it. For example, you might have an alternate "* - Details" View using a UrlKey of `myid/.*`. Whatever that detection is just add a bit of code to the View that display the banner so it knows not to do its job under those conditions. The trick is to exit out of the Hero View before outputting anything.

Here is a function (dependency on RazorBlade) that will return true/false if the URL has the param:

```
public bool qsHasKey(string paramName = "demo") {
  return Text.Has(Request.QueryString[paramName], false);
}
```

So then you just call it like normal. What is not so normal is having your View do close to nothing, since its Razor, this means you need to `return` early (instead of exit). So near the start of your hero's View, just put

```
// no hero needed if we are displaying Details
if(qsHasKey("myid")) {
  return; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremys answer is correct for many use cases.

Alternative #1 is to create a details page with just the details view, and link to that. We did that in the news-app, which has an App-Setting where you can configure which page should be the details page - and then no matter where the news-list was placed (like on home with a lot of other modules), the details will still open on the right place.

Alternative #2 is to create something ajax-style, like an expanding section or a lightbox.